# Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-aria/interactions'

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, native-base

I'm adding native base to my existing expo react project. I've added the necessary packages as described in their [installation guide](https://docs.nativebase.io/install-expo), but each time I get this error, I've tried multiple iterations of installing and uninstalling, deleting node modules and running it again, adding `react-aria` directly (including just `@react-aria/interactions`), but then I always get a new error with each package added.

The advice on most stack overflow posts seems to be "delete node modules and try again", but that has no effect for me.

My `package.json` is pretty straightforward:

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
"expo": "~39.0.2",
"expo-ads-admob": "~8.3.0",
"expo-cli": "^4.2.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
"firebase": "^7.9.0",
"mobx": "^6.1.7",
"mobx-react": "^7.1.0",
"native-base": "^3.1.0",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
"react-native-elements": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.4",
"react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
"styled-components": "^5.3.1",
"styled-system": "^5.1.5",
"uuid": "^8.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
"@expo/webpack-config": "^0.15.0",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.11.0",
"json-server": "^0.16.3"
},
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, I thought it was something to do with my project, but after creating a new expo project following their instructions, I'm getting the same issue. It's possible something is broken with `native-base` npm dependencies.

Comment: @Thomas see my answer below. Use yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked the NAtive Base creators about it: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4011

Basically they say that it's a problem only hen using npm and not yarn, so they ask that we use yarn for now.